# What to do with duplicate questions that have an accepted answer, which are not yet marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, accepted-answer

I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55637446) appearing on front page, which is clearly a duplicate of [this question that I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43220140). The code in both questions will result in a stack overflow due to the same reason. The answers are almost identical. However the question is already answered and marked as solved by OP. Should I still close it as a duplicate?

This was originally posted on Meta Stack Exchange, but πάντα ῥεῖ has suggested that specific SE sites may have different policies on duplicates, so I decided to ask here.

Comment: It happens often that duplicates get answers before you close them, so it's normal situation. Sometimes even seasoned users find it easier to answer than searching for duplicates (because SO search is so "good" I guess). Just vote-close. The magic may happens or may not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The code in both questions will result in a stack overflow due to the same reason. The answers are almost identical. However the question is already answered and marked as solved by OP.

Well, supposing your answer solves the problem posted in the OP, I don't see why you putting a duplicate vote would be a bad action.

Comment: My initial concern is not rep farming (though, that's a valid one), but the fact the question is already marked as solved. It just feels really werid to have a question closed after the OP thinks his question has been solved. I once observed a question (in ~2017, not 2011 antique), which should clearly be put on hold (ask for library suggestion), but it got marked as solved before I even see it, went away safely. It is not exactly the same thing, but I feel they are somewhat similiar.

Comment: @glee8e No, the accept (solved) mark doesn't make any difference.

Comment: IMO, asking a user to preemptively mark their answer as community wiki prior to close-voting some other question with the question they answered as the duplicate-target is going a bit far. Yes, a user *could be* attempting to rep-farm by directing people to their answer. However, it's *expected* (and much more likely, IMO) that users who are quite active in a tag will answer questions which are later used as dup-targets. This is even more prevalent in low-traffic tags. In addition, users are, of course, more familiar with questions they've answered, so they come to mind as dup-targets easier.

Comment: We should be aware of the *possibility* that someone might be trying to rep-farm by inappropriately closing questions as duplicates of questions which they've answered, but that's usually something that's indicated by a *pattern* of closures, not a single closure, or even several closures spread over weeks or months (there have been some instances on single popular questions). People rep-farming in this way doesn't appear to be so prevalent that we should be suggesting that users proactively mark their answers as community wiki when they use a question they've answered as a dup-target.

Comment: I disagree with your advice against using your own answers to close other questions. There is no need to have your post CW'd. You have every right to earn reputation for your old answers, especially since you had the restraint to close the post instead of answering it again to get more cheap rep.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ usually rep-farming means that someone is doing something more for the rep than for the benefit to the community. i.e. aggressively marking things as duplicates. Getting some rep for cleaning up duplicates in a helpful manner is not rep-farming. (Though the two may look similar)

Comment: I downvoted this answer because there's almost no answer here. "Sure, why not?" isn't a reason to do anything on SO.

Comment: _"I don't see why you shouldn't put a duplicate vote would be a bad action."_ Can you rephrase this? It does not make sense and I cannot parse what you mean by it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I edited the answer; looks like Pi tried to say the same thing two different ways and didn't delete the entirety of the first attempt.

Answer (score 9):

## Duplicate Handling

For whether you flag as a duplicate, consider the purpose of duplicate flagging:

> There’s often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question around, as people tend to ask and search using completely different words, and the better our coverage, the better odds our fellow programmers can find the answer they’re looking for.

<sub>From [Linking Duplicate Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/20/linking-duplicate-questions/)</sub>

Does flagging as a duplicate still further this goal? Yes. It connects the questions so that searchers can find the answer that helps them most. So yes, you should.

## What it means for a question to have an accepted answer

Stack Overflow doesn't use the term "solved." This is intentional. The idea that a post has been "solved" is contrary to SO's mission: to create a high quality repository of knowledge. The site does *not* exist to provide people with personalized help. It exists to document standard, robust solutions to specific problems that are encountered in a wide variety of contexts. It is furthermore intended to stimulate readers' ability to work through their own problems rather than feed their dependency on others for help. Using the word "solved" implies that SO's mission was to help that *particular* user with a problem, rather than document the information. This might be a bit pedantic, but it's important to understand the distinction.

Instead, SO uses the term "accepted." This means that the user posting the question believes that particular answer to be the most appropriate solution to their problem. This gives the answer a level of priority over the others, with the assumption being that the answer is probably in the best position to evaluate whether or not the answer actually works. This assumption is arguably a bit too strong, as the asker sometimes doesn't have the level of knowledge to evaluate which one is best for concerns other than whether the code actually runs (like maintainability or security), but it's what we have.

None of this, however, conflicts with the reasons for why we mark questions as duplicates. So a question having an accepted answer should not factor into duplicate closing.

Answer (score 5):

Solved implies "case closed", that is hardly ever the case on Stack Overflow unless a hard lock is placed on something by a moderator. You can still add answers after that green checkmark appears, you can still close as a duplicate.

And why not, because it is still the goal to provide people with the superior answer. The fact that the author of a question was helped by an answer is completely irrelevant to that process, we dupe close to help the many, not the one.

Answer (score 0):

> However the question is already answered and marked as solved by OP.

This has no relevance when closing a question as duplicate. Nor does question age. Votes may matter - we only care about keeping the dupe that is clearest and of best technical quality.

> Should I still close it as a duplicate?

In general, yes. But the post that's of the lowest quality should be closed, which is not necessarily the newest one.

For this specific case, it is sensible to not suggest questions where you have posted the question/an answer yourself as target dupes, since you are partial. The site works so that questions that are frequently picked as dupe targets get higher "frequent" rank and more attention, so picking your own questions as dupes might be seen as self serving.

So the most correct approach is to not cast any close votes but just leave a comment: "possible duplicate of `<link>`" and then leave it to other users to make the call.

But then, questions where you have participated yourself are the easiest ones to remember, so I'm not sure how far to take the impartial argument. The most important is that dupes get closed. In your case you need 4 others (or 1 gold badge user) to cast dupe votes too, so the system is pretty safe against abuse no matter.